# Google Chrome Z-index is not working

Tags: css

I am working on one website. There is chat box which display well in firefox. But not in google chrome. I have try many trick but i cant fix it. Will you give me some solutions for it.

The site is http://ng.whoosmart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=53

Its opencart site when you open this url in firefox its display well when you scroll down page it is in the footer.

But when you open in google chrome then its not display when you scroll down to page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add chatbox div in the end just before closing of body tag it will position correctly on chrome.